# laravel function show in controller

Tags: laravel, model, controller, routes

I'm trying to show lessons from the course when i clicked on.

model lesson

```
public function course(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}
```

model course

```
 public function lesson() {
   return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
```

}

show controller

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $cours = Course::findOrFailnd($id);
    $lessons = course::findOrFail($id)->lesson;
    return view('pages.lessons', compact('lessons', 'cours'));

}
```

page lesson

```
<div class="form-group">
    <strong>Lessons : </strong>
    @foreach ($lessons as $lesson )

    {{$lesson->long_text}}


    @endforeach
</div>
```

web routes

```
Route::resource('pages/lessons', 'LessonsController@show')->name('pages.lessons');
```

and i have this error:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::name(), 1 passed in C:\wamp64\www\learn2code\routes\web.php on line 21 and exactly 2 expected
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `$cours = Course::findOrFailnd($id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[For resource controllers its `names` instead of `name`:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes)

> Naming Resource Routes
>
> By default, all resource controller actions have a route name;
>   however, you can override these names by passing a names array with
>   your options:

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->names([
    'create' => 'photos.build'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Model Course

```
public function lessons() {
    return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('pages/lessons/{course}', 'LessonsController@show')->name('pages.courses.lessons');
```

OR

```
Route::get('pages/courses/{course}/lessons', 'LessonsController@show')->name('pages.courses.lessons');
```

Controller show method

```
public function show(Course $course) {
    return view('pages.lessons', compact('course'));

}
```

page lesson

```
<div class="form-group">
    <strong>Lessons : </strong>
    @foreach ($course->lessons as $lesson)

        {{$lesson->long_text}}

    @endforeach
</div>
```